# PHP Mailing script, Email isn't coming through

Tags: php, email

I tested this script using my email address and the script below worked, however upon changing the email address the script will not work. I have however copy and pasted the email address (the one that didn't work in the script) into my sky email client and sent an email which has worked.

This is the script (please note there is no checking or any validation on this script yet)

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($subject));
$name = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($name));
$message = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($message));
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">";
$headers[] = "Subject: {".$subject."}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
$to = "example@example.com";
$email = mail($to,$subject,$message,implode("\r\n", $headers));
if($email){
header('location: thankyou-email.php');
}
else{
header('Location: contact-us.php');
}
```

I have tried with different headers but this also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any errors???

Comment: I would try a minimal script, something like `$sent = mail('my@address.com', 'my subject', 'my message', implode("\r\n", $headers));` and check if it comes through. If it's not, your mail most probably got stuck in a spam filter. And you might want to take a look at one [one](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) [of](http://swiftmailer.org/) [the numerous](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+mailer+library&oq=php+mailer+library&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.2579j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=php+mail+library) php mail libraries

Comment: Please consider using a decent mailer class like PHPMailer instead of the raw php `mail()` function.

Comment: As Spudley mentions above, the raw mail() functions have somewhat outlived their usefulness. For most use-cases, you'll want to use a mailing class that lets you authenticate through SMTP. PHPMailer is great: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @MalcolmDiggs only issue is does phpmailer offer SMTP authentication to a remote server?

Comment: @Mathlight checked the error_log and nothing at all it redirects as expected... well supposedly expected

Comment: Yes it does, I use it for that. 

The point being: With the errors you're experiencing above, the problem could be on the receiving end (the mail server receiving the email you're sending out). Some mail servers (like gmail) will auto-reject most incoming mail when it isn't authenticated in any way (as would be the case of mail generated through the mail() class). 

But you could also switch to an external mailing system like MailGun, MailChimp, SendGrid, etc. All great options.

Comment: @MalcolmDiggs i will give it a try currently it is sending to an address on our exchange server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using $headers[0], $headers[1] etc. 
also, gmail saves your email in its buffer so when you'll receive your first email (after correcting your code), you may also receive a bunch of other messages which you had send with $headers[].

My working code is:

```
    <?php
    $subject = "aaa";
    $name ="aaa";
    $message = "aaa";
    $subject = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($subject));
    $name = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($name));
    $message = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($message));
    $headers = array();
    $headers[0] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[1] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[2] = "From: ".$name;
    $headers[3] = "Subject: {".$subject."}";
    $headers[4] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    $to = "My_email@gmail.com";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,implode("\r\n", $headers));
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer this. However i don't use gmail at all, the email is been sent directly to our exchange server. Also as i haven't added the numbers into $headers[] as it is an array it would automatically add the next number of the array, as its the same as not specifying the key when writing an array. The issue with the code is not that it doesn't work as i have tested and it does work it is only on certain email address's, which i have tested by sending an email through sky email (yahoo) which is recieved perfectly